# Bind ember input values to nested fields

Tags: data-binding, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have several input fields that are logically grouped together. I'd like to bind them to the same object within a controller but with different fields. Something along the lines of this:

```
{{input valueBinding=someObject.someNestedField}}
```

Is this possible in Ember? If so, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{input value=someObject.someNestedField}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jobimuyo/1/edit

If you do `valueBinding` you need to put it in quotes

```
{{input valueBinding='someObject.someNestedField'}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jobimuyo/2/edit